# jqGrid rowNum option issue

Tags: jqgrid

Assume that row numbers is changed from 10 to 30 in navgrid and that we handle onPaging like so:

```
...
onPaging: function(pgbtn) {
    var rowNum = $(this).getGridParam('rowNum');
    return 'stop';
}
```

- In jqGrid 4.4.0 rowNum will be 30.
- In jqGrid 4.7.0 rowNum will be 10.

Is this expected behaviour because I think rowNum should be 30?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the execution is changed in (compare [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.base.js#L2200) in jqGrid 4.7.0 with [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.0/js/grid.base.js#L1932) in jqGrid 4.4.0). jqGrid first changed the ``` rowNum``and then called ```onPaging` in jqGrid 4.4.0, but in jqFeid 4.7.0 the oder is changed.

To access to the new value of `rowNum` one should get the value of `rowNum` from the corresponding `<select>` control directly. If you use the `pager` at the bottom of the grid then the corresponding code could be the following:

```js
onPaging: function (pgButton) {
    var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"),
        newRowNum = parseInt($(p.pager).find(".ui-pg-selbox").val());

    if (...) { // some stop criteria
        return "stop";
    }
}
```

If you use `toppager: true` option then jqGrid create the pager on the top of the grid and then it change the value of `toppager` parameter from `true` to the selector id of the pager. So you can use the code like

```js
onPaging: function (pgButton) {
    var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"),
        newRowNum = parseInt($(p.toppager).find(".ui-pg-selbox").val());

    if (...) { // some stop criteria
        return "stop";
    }
}
```

which just use `p.toppager` instead of `p.pager` in the previous code example.

In case of usage *both* top and bottom pagers you have to get both values and choose the value which is not equal to the value of `rowNum` parameter:

```js
onPaging: function (pgButton) {
    var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"),
        rowNumBottom = parseInt($(p.pager).find(".ui-pg-selbox").val()),
        rowNumTop = parseInt($(p.toppager).find(".ui-pg-selbox").val()),
        newRowNum = p.rowNum === rowNumTop ? rowNumBottom: rowNumTop;

    if (...) { // some stop criteria
        return "stop";
    }
}
```

By the way there are exist close problem in case of calling `onPaging` after other changing in the pager, for example if the user typed new value in the input box with new pager number.

I'm developing now **free jqGrid** as [my fork](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) on github. I change the code of jqGrid so that `onPaging` receives the second parameter which is object with the properties `newPage`, `currentPage`, `lastPage`, `currentRowNum` and `newRowNum`. The corresponding jQuery event `jqGridPaging` are added too. Moreover I have changed the value of the first parameter so that it corresponds [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pager#events) and the value will be the string `"first"`, `"last"`, `"prev"` or `"next"` in case when the user clicked on the corresponding pager button. The version 4.7 used in reality the `id` of the corresponding pager buttons instead of `"first"`, `"last"`, `"prev"`, `"next"`. So the strings `"first"`, `"last"`, `"prev"`, `"next"` could be appended with `"_"` and the id of the pager (or toppager).

Thus one can just use `options.newRowNum` or `options.currentRowNum` directly in the code of callback:

```js
onPaging: function (pgButton, options) {
    // one can use options.newRowNum directly
    // the value options.currentRowNum is identical to 
    // $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "rowNum")

    if (...) { // some stop criteria
        return "stop";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of top and bottom pagers, I would add to Oleg's response:

```
onPaging: function (pgButton) {
    var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"),
        rowNumBottom = parseInt($(p.pager).find(".ui-pg-selbox").val()),
        rowNumTop = parseInt($(p.toppager).find(".ui-pg-selbox").val()),
        newRowNum = p.rowNum === rowNumTop ? rowNumBottom: rowNumTop;

    if (...) { // some stop criteria
        return "stop";
    }

    // update the current value so subsequent changes are detected
    p.rowNum = newRowNum;

}
```

This handles the case that the user changes the value on the top pager, then changes it again on the bottom pager. The code above will keep detecting the top pager value.